# How to import a function with a variable and make that variable global

Tags: python, telnetlib

config.py

```
import telnetlib

def my_function(a):
    tn=telnetlib.Telnet(a)
```

main.py

```
import config.py

HOST=172.25.25.5
config.my_function(HOST)

tn.write(b"show run".encode('ascii') + b"\n")
```

This code will return 'tn' is not defined. How do I gain access to the variable 'tn' after importing from config.py to main.py?

Comment: You need `global tn` in `my_function`. But that will create `config.tn`.

Comment: `return tn` in config.py and then `tn = config.my_function(HOST)` in main.py...